# Calculate Center of Gravity Based on Four Load Cells in C

Tags: c

In C, I'm reading weight values from four load cells, let's call them:

```
UINT16 loadcell1
UINT16 loadcell2
UINT16 loadcell3
UINT16 loadcell4
```

They create a rectangle in a 2D plane, each load cell being a corner of that plane. The location of each load cell within the 2D plane is known. An object will be placed on a uniform metal sheet that uses each load cell as a corner. What would be the best way to calculate the center of gravity? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need the load values AND the locations of load cells to compute the COG. Doesn't seem like you have sufficient data.

Comment: There are too many known unknowns, unknown knows, and unknown unknowns in this question.

Comment: How is that last statement even remotely helpful? You might as well just say, "Boo! Don't like question!"

Comment: @BrianSchoonmaker - sorry, I thought from your picture that you might appreciate the joke. Irony is dead.

Comment: No - my bad. I just heard that way too many times from CS professors - it gets old after a while.

Answer (score 1):

In the one dimensional case, I think you can find the COG by matching the torques, where the torque is just force times distance. (Ignore the tilt in the diagram, if the lever arm is not level, then the equation for torque is going to have a `sin(Ɵ)` in it, which makes things complicated).

[image]

So the equation that needs to be solved is

```
W1 * x = W2 * (L - x)
```

where the length `L` is the distance between the two weights. Solving for `x` gives

```
x = (L * W2) / (W1 + W2);
```

If I'm not mistaken, in the 2D case, the `x` and `y` values can be solved independently (assuming the rectangle is aligned to the x and y axes).

You might want to confirm all of this over on the physics stack exchange.